# Pandas append() and remove duplicates messes up the index

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am **scraping** some data from a basketball site and the plan is to automatically update it when new data is added.

I get the data

```
stats = pd.read_html('URL', header=[0, 1])
player_stats = stats[4]

player_stats.to_csv('stats.csv')
```

Append it

```
with open('stats.csv', 'a') as f:
    player_stats.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

Remove duplicates (method 1)

```
old_data = pd.read_csv('stats.csv')
data = old_data.drop_duplicates(subset='Unnamed: 1_level_0', keep='last')
data.to_csv('stats.csv')
```

Remove duplicates (method 2)

```
old_data = pd.read_csv('stats.csv')
bool_series = data["Unnamed: 1_level_0"].duplicated(keep='last') 
bool_series 
data = data[~bool_series] 
data.to_csv('stats.csv')
```

The problem I face is that after the [original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZtKW.png) is appended with the [new data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMyJc.png) the remove duplicate method [messes up the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEMUh.png) of the file making future appending and removing duplicates impossible as duplicates [are not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ0bs.png) as such anymore...

Why is the new index added and how do I fix that?

Comment: Instead of appending data directly to the file, make use of Panda's function concat(). Be aware of argument axis.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about that, I'm still new to pandas.
However, after spending a few hours on this I realized I don't need the new data, I can just overwrite everything and done :facepalm

Comment: Glad I helped :). Let me post it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of appending data directly to the file, make use of [Panda's function concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). Be aware of argument axis.